# JAXB object with custom scheme

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to produce this this XML:

```
<payment xmlns="http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/payment">
    <merchant-account-id>1233</merchant-account-id>
    ........
</payment>
```

I tried this with JAXB:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace="http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/payment")
public class AuthorizeRequest { 

    @XmlElement(name = "merchant-account-id")
    public String merchantAccountId;
    ..........
}
```

But I get only this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<payment>
    <merchant-account-id>1233</merchant-account-id>
</payment>
```

Do you know how I can set custom `xmlns` for the root tag `payment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do you know how I can set custom xmlns for the root tag payment?
```

Remove the @XmlType and add instead namespace in your @XmlRootElement. Something like this.

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "payment", namespace="http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/payment")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class AuthorizeRequest {

        @XmlElement(name = "merchant-account-id")
        public String merchantAccountId;
        ..........

    }
```

Output would be like this, which you probably didn't want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:payment xmlns:ns2="http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/payment">   
   <merchant-account-id>1233</merchant-account-id>
</ns2:payment>
```

If you want to remove this header (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`) set the JAXB_FRAGMENT to true.

```
   JAXBContext jaxbContext  = JAXBContext.newInstance(AuthorizeRequest.class);
   Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
   jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE); //remove header
   AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = new AuthorizeRequest();
   authorizeRequest.setMerchantAccountId("123123");
   //jaxbMarshaller.marshal(authorizeRequest,System.out); //print to console
```

And finally to remove the extra ns2 select the package that AuthorizeRequest.class resides and create a package-info.java file and add the the following annotation. You may change it if you needed

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/payment", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = { @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/payment", prefix = "") })
package com.foo.bar;
```